# getting XML from NSData response of an NSURLSessionDataTask request

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I send a `NSURLSessionDataTask` and I get `NSData` as response. It should contain `XML` in it. But I am not able to get it.

When I send a `curl` request on command line, it works as expected

```
NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) { //5
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [response description]);
        NSLog(@"%@", data);   // some data I can not understand.
    }
}];
```

Request:

```
{
    "Content-Type" = "application/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"";
}
```

Response

```
{ status code: 207, headers {
    "Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 1282;
    "Content-Type" = "text/xml";
```

Please provide pointers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`text/xml` is just XML string so convert response data to string by

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Your code will be:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) { //5
    if (!error) {
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
    }
}];
```